# Time complexity for generic algorithms

Tags: math, time-complexity

I was wondering, if my thought process looks odd.
After digging for a bit on time complexity for general code, say:

```
Alg(x):
   statements...
   functions...
   ...
```

1. Can we say that T(Alg(x)) = T<sub>1</sub>(statement) + T<sub>2</sub>(functions) + T<sub>3</sub>(...) then break them apart and keep going in depth until we can go no further? This can lead to the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) which I can see if my previous statement is correct.
2. From (1) (assuming it holds) then any alg. such that it's non-recursive can we say T(Alg(x)) is:

```
Alg(x):
 block 1 -> {
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            statements
        }
    }
  }
  block 2 -> {
    for j -> k // T(K)
    call_1() // T(N_1)
    call_2() // T(N_2)
  }
```

T(Alg(x)) = T<sub>1</sub>(b<sub>1</sub>) + T<sub>2</sub>(b<sub>2</sub>)
where T<sub>1</sub>(b<sub>1</sub>) = T(N) * T<sub>2</sub>(f<sub>2</sub>) = T(N) * (T(M) * T<sub>3</sub>(s<sub>3</sub>)) as general where N, M are input sizes, and s<sub>3</sub> are more breakable parts.
As for T<sub>2</sub>(b<sub>2</sub>) we have T(K) + T(N<sub>1</sub>) + T(N<sub>2</sub>)

Comment: If your algorithm only has loops where the loop body's time complexity is the same on every iteration, and the loop has a definite number of iterations, and there are no conditional statements or other kinds of branching, then sure. But many algorithms do not meet these criteria.

Comment: As a quick sanity check, what does your technique say about `alg(n): while n > 1 { if n is even { n /= 2; } else { n = 3*n + 1; } }`?

Comment: I tried to come up with a sensible approach all day, but using above T(alg(n)) = T1(b1) where b1 is block 1 { while ... } but when I break this further I get T1(b1) = T1(s1)*max(T2(s2), T3(s3)) where s1 is while, s2 if and s3 else. but T1(s1) can't be computed as its directly depends on max(T2(s2), T3(s3)). Since this does not violate (1) I see that it won't be generic. Hmmm...